# SQL query to get count based on filtered status

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I have a table which has two columns, `CustomerId` & `Status` (A, B, C).

A customer can have multiple status in different rows.

I need to get the count of different status based on following rules:

1. If the status of a customer is A & B, he should be counted in Status A.
2. If status is both B & C, it should be counted in Status B.
3. If status is all three, it will fall in status A.

What I need is a table with status and count.

Could please someone help?

I know that someone would ask me to write my query first, but i couldn't understand how to implement this logic in query.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could play with different variations of this:

```
select customerId, 
       case when HasA+HasB+HasC = 3 then 'A' 
            when HasA+HasB = 2 then 'A'
            when HasB+HasC = 2 then 'B'
            when HasA+HasC = 2 then 'A'
            when HasA is null and HasB is null and HasC is not null then 'C'
            when HasB is null and HasC is null and HasA is not null then 'A'
            when HasC is null and HasA is null and HasB is not null then 'B'
       end as overallStatus
from 
    (
    select customerId, 
           max(case when Status = 'A' then 1 end) HasA,
           max(case when Status = 'B' then 1 end) HasB,
           max(case when Status = 'C' then 1 end) HasC
    from   tableName
    group by customerId
    ) as t;
```

Comment: Yes, it gives the desired results except that is returning null for a single status. I am still trying to get it correct. If you could include that too, it could be an accepted answer.

Answer (score 0):

I like to use Cross Apply for this type of query as it allows for use of the calculated status in the Group By clause.

Here's my solution with some sample data.

```
Declare @Table Table (Customerid int, Stat varchar(1))

INSERT INTO @Table  (Customerid, Stat ) 
VALUES
(1, 'a'), 
(1 , 'b'),
(2, 'b'),
(2 , 'c'),
(3, 'a'),
(3 , 'b'),
(3, 'c')



SELECT
ca.StatusGroup 
, COUNT(DISTINCT Customerid) as Total
FROM
@Table t
CROSS APPLY
   (VALUES
        (
         CASE WHEN 
             EXISTS 
             (SELECT 1 FROM @Table x where x.Customerid = t.CustomerID and x.Stat = 'a') 
             AND EXISTS
            (SELECT 1 FROM @Table x where x.Customerid = t.CustomerID and x.Stat = 'b') 
             THEN 'A'
      WHEN 
            EXISTS 
             (SELECT 1 FROM @Table x where x.Customerid = t.CustomerID and x.Stat = 'b') 
             AND EXISTS
            (SELECT 1 FROM @Table x where x.Customerid = t.CustomerID and x.Stat = 'c') 
             THEN 'B'
             ELSE t.stat
        END 
        )
     ) ca (StatusGroup)

GROUP BY ca.StatusGroup
```

I edited this to deal with Customers who only have one status... in which case it will return A, B or C dependant on the customers status

Comment: Thanks DaveFoyf, but i guess first solution is more readable. Apart from that, i think the execution time will be more in you solution as you are using cross join.